# jQuery Spectrum - how to reinitialise with updated palette array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery spectrum with 7 different colour pickers.

The pickers are all loaded with the same 6 colours - if a new active colour is selected from the colour picker I want all of the palettes to re initialise with the original colours + the new active colours.

Spectrum's functionality can get close to this out the box but sadly it still shows new selected colours even if they are not active and I exclusively want active or the original palette only.

here is what one of my calls looks like:

```
/* FG COLOR */
function fgColor(color) {
    var hexColor = "#ffffff";
    if (color) {
        hexColor = color.toHexString();
    }
    $(".fgcolor").css("color", hexColor);
}

$(".fgcolorpicker").spectrum({
    showInput: true,
    showInitial: true,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    showSelectionPalette: false,
    showPalette: true,
    palette: [
        ['#3C3F3D', '#98B82A', '#D8A51A'],
        ['#81904D', '#ffffff', '#98B82A']
    ],
    color: "#3C3F3D",
    maxSelectionSize: 1,
    change: fgColor
});

fgColor($(".fgcolorpicker").spectrum("get"));
```

The above works fine... however when I want to redraw the palette I get stuck... I thought passing just the palette back into spectrum would work like:

```
$(".fgcolorpicker").spectrum({
    palette: [
        ['#3C3F3D', '#98B82A', '#D8A51A'],
        ['#81904D', '#ffffff', '#98B82A']
    ]
});
```

but it doesn't like it and only updates if I pass the full original call back with different hex's.

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Documentation for jQuery Spectrum says**](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#methods-option) says :

`$("#picker").spectrum("option", optionName, newOptionValue);` is the syntax for updating. So you might try the below.

```
$('.fgcolorpicker').spectrum("option", "palette", [
    ['#3C3F3D', '#98B82A', '#D8A51A'],
    ['#81904D', '#ffffff', '#98B82A']
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I overlooked that - I was scanning too hard for a reference to "palette" - thanks so much - jQuery small learning steps!

Comment: @user1523591 I don't myself knew about this till you asked this question. Glad to have helped you by the way :)